# What is known about Nicolas van Saberhagen?

Tags: cryptonote, saberhagen

What if anything is conclusively known about Nicolas van Saberhagen?

Are there any educated guesses about who this person or group may be (similar to how there are guesses about the identity of Satoshi Nakamoto) based on available clues? For example is it likely that this person or group is an academic or cryptographer based solely on the level of knowledge required to draft the CryptoNote white paper?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reasonably, we have no real idea. This person or group is currently unknown just like Satoshi Nakamoto. The text in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote#Origins_2) sums up some thoughts in the community about the creator(s) of CryptoNote:

> The author of the white paper went by the name Nicolas van Saberhagen,
>   although like Satoshi Nakamoto (the author of the bitcoin white paper)
>   that name is likely a pseudonym. Saberhagen's true identity and
>   location remains unknown. Some have claimed that the real creator is
>   someone in the bitcoin community. Adam Back, Nick Szabo and even
>   Satoshi Nakamoto himself have been floated as possible
>   suspects, but there is little to no evidence actually supporting
>   those claims.
>
> Stanford Bitcoin Group’s possible involvement in creation of the
>   CryptoNote protocol has also been discussed. Prior to CryptoNote
>   cryptocurrency protocol, the domain cryptonote.org hosted an encrypted
>   message application also named CryptoNote. This application was
>   developed by the members of the Stanford Bitcoin Group but had not
>   received wide recognition. This website currently hosts the CryptoNote
>   technology.

Further reading:

http://web.archive.org/web/20141205173019/http://thebitcoinnews.com/2014/11/24/bytecoin-satoshis-new-project/

http://bytecoiner.org/bytecoin-source-of-origin/

https://medium.com/@AckermanRonald/stanford-wide-gate-steep-steps-ad95cfccca21

Comment: more interesting links: https://web.archive.org/web/20140628091251/http://bitcoinbarbie.com/cryptonote-open-source-technology-concept/              https://web.archive.org/web/20160130004326/https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=740112.0

Comment: He was supposed to give a talk on cryptonote at a conference about 18 months ago, but then he just ended up calling in via Skype, and apparently wasn't well understood due to using a voice changer to disguise his voice:  https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=658884.msg10993521#msg10993521

Comment: That photo of the people listening to the voice changed Skype call is crazy.

Comment: In the first link they call themselves "Johannes Meier, Maurice Planck, Max Jameson, Brandon Hawking, Catherine Erwin, Albert Werner and Marec Plíškov". But these names all come from scientists :D